# Is there any difference between these oracle queries?

Tags: oracle

I have two oracle queries

1) created_dt between sysdate+7 and sysdate

2) created_dt between sysdate and sysdate+7

Is this two query will give same result??

Comment: 'between oldest date and newest date'  is the correct format.   So: No they are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

the first will never return any rows.

you can consider a between

```
where col between A and B
```

to be the same as

```
where col >= A and col <= B
```

so your first one is illogical as its

```
created_dt >= sysdate+7 and created_dt <= sysdate
```

both conditions can never be true.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, construct `x BETWEEN a AND b` is equivalent to `a <= x AND x <= b`.

Obviously, if `a > b`, this constraint is going to yield empty result.

In other words, swapping interval ends does matter: first must be less or equal than second.